# Get the content of title tag from a webpage with PHP

Tags: php

Hi,

I am trying to get the content fo the title tag from a page within my site. However, file_get_contents is disabled so seems like cURL is my only option. This is what I am trying:

```
$domain="http://example.com";
ob_start();
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $domain. '/blog/index.php?page=4');
$getit = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
ob_end_clean();
preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $getit, $matches);
$title= $matches[1];
```

I had to use ob_start and clean because otherwise the called page is embedded onto my final hmtl code which I dont need. I only need to get the tag value and have $title display it but it displays nothing. Whats the problem here?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try to print $getit  ? or $matches ? and see what is the result

Comment: Yes, the result of getit is a "1" but $matches prints nothing but "array".

Comment: in full HTML can you see <title> my title </title> ?

Comment: Yes, the page has the tags. Also, please see my last comment, I made a mistake and I just corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

The final code should be

```
$domain="http://example.com";
ob_start();
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $domain. '/blog/index.php?page=4');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$getit = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
ob_end_clean();
preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $getit, $matches);
$title= $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing that line. However, seems like the ob_start() is not necessary either. One more question, the encoding of the called page is different than the actual page. Is it possible to change the encoding?

Comment: Hey try to use curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");